# How to run multiple thread groups one after another for a particular period of time using scheduler in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am doing volume testing for an application for which I have to prepare a lot of a data using a jmeter script. So I want to automate the script so that it runs for a period of time specified.

My Testplan contains 10 Thread Groups:
ThreadGroup 1
ThreadGroup 2
ThreadGroup 3
.
.
.
 ThreadGroup 10

What I have been trying is that I want my ThreadGroup 1 to run for 1st 30 minutes, then ThreadGroup 2 runs for next 30 minutes and so on till ThreadGroup 10 runs for last 30 minutes.

How can I achieve this configuration using scheduler in jmeter? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want Thread to execute full 30 minutes or until it's done maximum of 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively` box in the [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

   [image: JMeter Run Thread Groups Consecutively]
2. In each of your [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) specify "Duration" of `1800` seconds, Also make sure you have "Loop Count" set to `Forever` or `-1` otherwise Thread Group will execute only this number of loops which is defined (by default 1)

   [image: JMeter Thread Groups Duration]

This way your Thread Groups will run one-by-one and each Thread Group will last for 30 minutes.

Check out [Getting Started with JMeter - A Basic Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial) to get familiarized with JMeter essential components